# How to merge 2 drives of a single pendrive?

Tags: windows-8, usb, merge

I have a pendrive which when connected shows two different drives with single partition each. How do I merge both these into one? I want it to show a single drive with no partitions when I connect it to my system. I have a windows 8 system.

Please let me know the solution for this.

Comment: What sort of pendrive ? Brand / model ?

Comment: none of the known brands. Issued by a private company to all its employees.

Comment: It sounds like the USB stick has firmware to make it appear as 2 disks. I don't think you'll be able to merge them into one.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, directly merging while keeping files from both partitions is not possible.

Generally, you would use `diskpart`, a command-line partitioning utility that comes with Windows, to accomplish this. The following procedure deletes all partitions and creates a new one spanning the entire drive. It is also possible to keep the first partition and grow it after deleting the second partition, maybe someone else will write a guide for that.

1. Backup all data from the thumb drive
2. Launch `diskpart`, e.g. from <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or the command prompt.
3. Enter `list disk` and locate your thumb drive’s number.
4. Enter `select disk X`, replacing `X` with your thumb drive’s number.
5. Verify you’re working on the correct drive with `list partition`.
6. **WARNING**: The following command will remove all partitions from the selected drive. You absolutely need to make sure you’re working on the correct drive.
7. Execute `clean`.
8. Execute `create partition primary`

After these steps, the drive contains a single unformatted partition. For assigning a drive letter and formatting, I recommend using the Disk Management GUI (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> `diskmgmt.msc`). Please note that partitioning removable drives is not possible from Disk Management, at least on Windows 7.

Comment: I tried using diskpart before. On using 'list disk' my pen drive doesn't show a single disk with partitions. Instead it shows 2 different disks. Also, diskmgmt.msc doesn't show removable disks.

Comment: That is rather... impossible. Disk Management definitely shows removable drives, otherwise you wouldn’t be able to reassign drive letters. Please make screenshots of Disk Management, `list disk` and Device Manager – in “by connection” view, expanded to your thumb drive.

Answer (score 0):

If the "list disk" command in diskpart shows the pen drive as two seperate disks. Then the USB pendrive is internaly built as two seperate drives and they can not be merged. But I agree with Daniel. I have never seen or heard of a pendrive built this way...

Comment: I have. Usually it's so they can implement crypto, with the first virtual device pretending to be a CD drive or similar containing a driver disk for the encrypted second.